# Alternative solution to handle backslashs in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, flask

I'm currently developing a Flask web app and it works fine in the IDE, but after I deployed my application to the cloud I've got the following problem that I can't solve:

1.Attempt

```
for i in os.listdir('data\\folder\\business'):
>> No such file or directory: 'data\\folder\\business'
```

As you see the escaping dosn't work properly on the server.
So I've tried several other ways:

2.Attempt

```
for i in os.listdir(r'data\folder\business'):
>> No such file or directory: 'data\\folder\\business'
```

3.Attemt

```
for i in os.listdir('data\folder\business'):
>> No such file or directory: 'data\folder\x08usiness'
```

Please tell me, if you know another way how to code backslashs in strings.

Comment: Are you assuming the server is running Windows? Pretty much all other systems use a forward slash (which is also supported on Windows), and that's what os.path.join and os.path.sep are for. Python 3 extends this with the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

Comment: Or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: to echo @YannVernier - look into `os.path.join`, the whole reason that exists is so that you don't have to worry about how different operating system construct file-path strings

Comment: As for escaping, the first two strings handled the backslashes but the third converted `\f` into form feed and `\b` into backspace per the [supported escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: @YannVernier Your solution worked! Thank you a lot

Comment: Which directory the script is running in?